# Parsing images and getting null result using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

So I am working out on some project and using Jsoup as my web parser. So the problem I am facing is that for some websites, the parsing is working perfectly and I am getting all the links. But for some websites, what I can notice is, the images are changing if I hover my mouse over them. So that is causing the issue that the image link is changing. Here are some screenshots of my code (My code is perfect and I just want to keep it confidential but I can show this much) :-

```
Elements elproductimage = link.getElementsByClass(productImageClass);
if(sNo == 6){
                for(Element elimage: elproductimage){
                    temp6 = elimage.absUrl("src");
                }
            }
```

This code should give me the link. I have taken the right class and everything.

In the image class, there is src available, but jsoup is not parsing that (I used debugger for that and I can see that there is no src in parsed section):-

[Grofers website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyKZc.png)

I checked this too, that all the images of these products are actually available here in network section of inspect element:-

[Network section of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzXN.png)

So please help me out, how can I parse this image link. What I can see is that these product images are having some kind of animation in them, so maybe the src is changing, that is why parser can't see it. Please help me out.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @dnault I actually thought that giving code image will be better. But thank you for your input. I have removed that code image and I edited the code. Thank you.

Comment: @KanishkChauhan Jsoup testing tool https://try.jsoup.org/, give it a try.

Comment: @kh3e yes I copied the element and pasted it here. only thing I am getting in images is "<img alt="Grofers Mother's Choice Refined Sugar">" that is it. No src available in parsed data.